# Network scan for vulnerabilities free tool

Tags: network-scanners, rc4

I have a huge distributed network with over 1000 servers and network devices. It is mix of operating systems.
I'm looking for some free tool to scan network for SSL v2, SSL v3, RC4,TLS v1.0 and older.
For example https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest suits perfectly for my needs, but it cannot scan many servers at the same time and most of the servers are not accessible from internet, so I need this tool to be working from inside of the network.
Do you have any suggestions? Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenVAS](http://www.openvas.org/) is very much like [NESSUS](https://www.tenable.com/products/nessus/select-your-operating-system) except that the vulnerability feed at the heart of the service is free.  Tenable security gives away the NESSUS tool freely, but charges for vulnerability updates.

Based on  your description of the problem, you can also use [NMAP](https://nmap.org/) scripts ([check out this article](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/sslv2.html)) to list service ciphers:

> **nmap -sV -sC *target***
>
> 443/tcp open   https   syn-ack
>   | sslv2:
>   |   SSLv2 supported
>   |   ciphers:
>   |     SSL2_DES_192_EDE3_CBC_WITH_MD5
>   |     SSL2_IDEA_128_CBC_WITH_MD5
>   |     SSL2_RC2_128_CBC_WITH_MD5
>   |     SSL2_RC4_128_WITH_MD5
>   |     SSL2_DES_64_CBC_WITH_MD5
>   |     SSL2_RC2_128_CBC_EXPORT40_WITH_MD5
>   |_    SSL2_RC4_128_EXPORT40_WITH_MD5